# When clause to map <enter> to stage a file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to switch to VSCode and one of the things that's bothering me is that I can't hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to stage one or more selected files. What is the correct when clause to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the file selected in the Source Control: Changes panel this seems to work:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "git.stage",
  "when": "sideBarFocus && activeViewlet == 'workbench.view.scm'"
}
```

from [vscode when clauses: active views/panels](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_activefocused-view-or-panel-when-clause-context).  This assumes the source control panel and a file therein has focus.

Comment: While this does enable staging a selected file, it also disables my ability to hit the enter key anywhere else.